# Подскажите пожалуйста как вынести код из блока else в отдельный метод java

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста как вынести первые 3 строки из блока else в отдельный метод. Уже пытался, но тогда символы не меняются местами.

```
public String reverseWord(String word) {
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0, j = letters.length - 1; i < j; ) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(letters[i]))
                i++;
            else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(letters[j]))
                j--;
            else {
                char current = letters[i];
                letters[i] = letters[j];
                letters[j] = current;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(letters);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поторопился, конечно же у вас есть контейнер)

Вам нужно передавать в функцию не сами примитивы, а контейнер и индексы для обмена:

```
public static void swapChars(char[] s, int i, int j) {
    char t = s[i]; s[i] = s[j]; s[j] = t;
}

swapChars(letters, i, j);
```

---

Это у вас swap функция получается.
В Java нельзя сделать такую функцию для примитивов.
Нужен враппер объект какой-нибудь.

Можно сделать вот такой костыль(K-комбинатор):

```
char swap(char a, char b) {
   return a;
}

letters[j] = swap(letters[i], letters[i]=letters[j]);
```

Первый аргумент копируется в функцию до того как выполняется присваивание для вычисления второго аргумента)